# Flutter - TextFormField geting blank when keyboard is hide

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout

In Flutter (Android )

I have two TextFormField in flutter app.
When I press back button. these text field is getting blank.

```
   class FirstScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  TextEditingController charectorsController = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController lengthCntroller = new TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('First Screen'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  myEditText(charectorsController, "Enter  charectors Word"),
                  myEditText(lengthCntroller, "Word length"),
                  RaisedButton(
                    child: Text('Launch screen'),
                    onPressed: () {
                      // Navigate to the second screen using a named route
                      // Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/second');
                      print("Rahul");
                      readFile();
                    },
                  )
                ],
              ),
            )),
      ),
    );
  }


}
```

and

```
    myEditText(TextEditingController myController, String s) {
  return new Container(
    margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
    child: new TextFormField(
      controller: myController,
      decoration: new InputDecoration(
        labelText: s,
        fillColor: Colors.white,
        border: new OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
          borderSide: new BorderSide(),
        ),
        //fillColor: Colors.green
      ),
      validator: (val) {
        if (val.length == 0) {
          return "Cannot be empty";
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      },
      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
      style: new TextStyle(
        fontFamily: "Poppins",
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Routing

```
void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
  title: 'Named Routes Demo',
  // Start the app with the "/" named route. In our case, the app will start
  // on the FirstScreen Widget
  initialRoute: '/',
  routes: {
    // When we navigate to the "/" route, build the FirstScreen Widget
    '/': (context) => FirstScreen(),
    // When we navigate to the "/second" route, build the SecondScreen Widget
    '/second': (context) => SecondScreen(),
  },
));
```

Comment: when are you pressing back button?

Comment: I click on TextFormField and Keyboard is show. After that I wrote some text in that. After that I press back button for closing keyboard and keyboard is close at same time TextFormField is getting bank.

Comment: Tried your code. Everything works, `TextFormField`s don't get blank

Comment: I think It may be because of I am using Routing.    I m posting My Routing code.

Comment: I am trying on Android emulator

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Transform your `StatelessWidget` to a `Stateful` one, it'll do the job. The problem is that by declaring the `TextEditingController` in a `StatelessWidget`, it'll be 'reset-ted' as the build function of the widget is called :'(. So you should do something like that:

```
class U extends StatefullWidget
  ....

class _UState extends State<U>
  final TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();

  Widget build(..) => TextField(controller: controller)
```

This should do the job :)